# Updating component state by Listening to socket events inside react hooks or handling them inside middleware? what are the downsides of each one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, listener, zustand

I have a `socket` class for dispatching and listening to events from the server.

The class has a method for synchronizing `state` between `server` and `client`.

here is how I listen to changes or events from the server.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useStore } from "./store"; // this is a zustand store object
import Game from "./game";

export const Lobby = ({ user }) => {
    const players = useStore(state => state.players);

    const dispatch = useStore(state => state.dispatch)


    const addPlayer = (player) => {
        dispatch({ type: "NEW_PLAYER", player })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // inside Game -> this.eventListeners[key].push(cb)
        Game.register('new-palyer', addPlayer); 
       
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
                players.map(player => <span>{player.name}</span>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

There is another way by subscription to the `store` inside the `Game` class and updating the `store` with any changes. I do not implement any but before any changes to the current structure of these listeners and dispatchers, I need to make a better decision by listing the `pros` and `cons` of each paradigm. I appreciate it if answered by the real example of the middleware paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Most socket has their own event listener. For example, this is how [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus#broadcasting) client listener works:

```js
primus.on('data', function (data) {
  if (primus.reserved(data.args[0])) return;

  primus.emit.apply(primus, data.args);
})
```

I assume your socket has this kind of listener too. The best way to sync **downstream** data, i.e: server to client, is in that handler. But for **upstream** data update, i.e: client to server, just put the handler on component like your code snippet.

Comment: We should have some considerations before any solution: `removing listeners on component unmount`, `how to know what side effects will be occurred due to more than one handler on two and more components`.

Comment: `more than one handler on two and more components` how about put handler to the componets common ancestor?

Comment: I should try that and find the result. before I tried `context api`  but also I had some issues when  I was registering handlers inside child components.

Comment: Just one solution that I should find consequences of that is not adding event handlers on the component mounting